# While loop continue running after using return to break in C

Tags: c

I got a segmentation fault in C programming, here is my simplified code:

```
int read(struct frame_entry *f)
{
    struct frame_entry* newptr = realloc(f, sizeof(struct frame_entry));
    int ret = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;

    while (f->len < MAX_FRAME_LEN)
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);

        switch(ch) {
        case FRAME_END:
            if (f->len){
                fclose(fp);
                return ret;
            }
        default:
            f->frame[f->len++] = ch;
            break;
        }
    }

frame_tail:
    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```

The running result is:
1, enter case FRAME_END
2, fclose(fp)
3, function return
4, while continue running but fp is zero
5, ch = fgetc(fp); drop a segmentation fault

The question is: why while loop continue running after function return?

---

## Solved

Finally I found that the problem is that struct frame_entry contains a file descriptor which opened, and I use fdopen to convert this file descriptor to a file pointer, but when I use fclose(fp) to free this file pointer, the file descriptor also be freed, then fgetc(fp) will cause segfault.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: add `break;` before `default`

Comment: `fp` is not init to anything.

Comment: `struct frame_entry* newptr = realloc(f, sizeof(struct frame_entry));` invalid `f` if realloc is a success.

Comment: Your code don't make sense, there are simply too many big errors.

Comment: Helo Stargateur, I deleted some part of my code to make these mode easier to read

Comment: Hello Thiru Shetty, I tried your suggestion but the issue still exist.

Comment: Don't delete code that my be needed to understand the root of the problem. Or even better, create a [mcve]. This may help you to find and solve the problem by yourself. Also, did you take the [tour] yet?

Comment: Why do you think `fp` would be zero? You don't set it to `NULL` after closing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused because you are using a pointer variable ie; `f` which is reallocted.
`realloc()` function may first try to increase the size of the block that a points to. However, it can instead allocate a new block, copy the data (or as much of the data as will fit) to the new block, and free the old block.

So while realloc() runs `f` may be pointing to an already deallocted memory. You should not use the variable `f`  instead use `newptr`.

Plus the file pointer is not properly initialized. It is a good practice to check if the file pointer is properly initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you are trying to read from a file pointer that is not initialized in the line `ch = fgetc(fp);` where fp is not initialized to any valid file. But I agree this might not cause a segfault. Like the answer above said, you need to use the new pointer after a call to `realloc`.

Since `null` is equivalent of the integer `0`, the loop runs because `f->len` never exceeds `MAX_FRAME_LEN`. This results in the loop running infinitely.